# Jquery update div content with multiple same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm builing a simple "like" service on my website. I'd like users to be able to click on link to like something, get the total likes (returned from php script)

I have problem getting the data from script to update div. This is what I have:

```
<div id="112" class="like">Like it</div>
<div id="113" class="like">Like it</div>
<div id="114" class="like">Like it</div>

<script>
$(".like" ).click(function() {
var idl = $(this).attr("id");
$.ajax({type:"POST", data: likeid=idl, url:"ajax/publike.php", 
            success: function(data){
                $(this).html(data);
            },
                        error: function(){
                    alert ("Error");
            }
        });
        return false;
});
</script>
```

I just would like to update the div with content I get from (data) but no update. If I change to `$(".like").html(data);` it works, but I have many class like, I only when to have the clicked div to update.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
    $(".like" ).click(function() {
    var idl = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({type:"POST", data: likeid=idl, url:"ajax/publike.php", 
                success: function(data){
                    $('#'+idl).html(data);
                },
                            error: function(){
                        alert ("Error");
                }
            });
            return false;
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<script>

$(".like" ).click(function()
{
    var idl = $(this).attr("id");

    var link = $(this);

    $.ajax({type:"POST", data: likeid=idl, url:"ajax/publike.php", 
    success: function(data)
    {
        link.html(data);
    },
    error: function()
    {
        alert ("Error");
    }});

    return false;
});

</script>
```

Comment: @Maël: did it help and fixed the problem? If yes, mark this answer as accepted and consider up voting it.

Answer (score 0):

By the time the AJAX callback runs, `this` is no longer in scope as the element which triggered the event.  You need to hold a reference to it:

```
$(".like" ).click(function() {
    var likedElement = $(this);
    var idl = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({type:"POST", data: likeid=idl, url:"ajax/publike.php", 
        success: function(data){
            likedElement.html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert ("Error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the context to the element when you make the ajax call. This is safer than just relying on a scope variable. If a second div is clicked before the first ajax call is returned, only the last divs html would get updated. This method will update both divs correctly.

```
<script>
$(".like" ).click(function() {

var div$ = $(this);

$.ajax({type:"POST", data: likeid=div$.attr("id"), url:"ajax/publike.php", context: div$,
            success: function(data){
                this.html(data);
            },
                        error: function(){
                    alert ("Error");
            }
        });
        return false;
});
</script>
```